# How can you add values to a linked list without using "->"?

Tags: c++

```
void CommunicationNetwork:: buildNetwork(){

    string citylist [] = {"Phoenix", "Denver", "Dallas", "St. Louis", "Chicago", "Atlanta", "Washington D.C.", "New York", "Boston"};

    head = ("Los Angeles", NULL, NULL);
    City *temp2 = new City;

    City *temp = new City;

    temp=head;

    for(int i=0;i<9;i++){

        temp2->cityName=citylist[i]; //=Pheonix
        temp->next=temp2;            //segmentation fault here
        temp=temp2;
    }
}
```

`City` is a struct for linked lists. `next` points to the next node. I get a segmentation fault because I am trying to dereference a NULL `next` value for `temp`. That is the only way I can think to add a value to `temp`. Is there another way I can replace NULL with `temp2` besides `temp->next= temp2`?

Comment: You need to move "temp2 = new City" inside the loop and point head to temp1.

Comment: Isn't head pointed to temp with the line "temp=head"?

Comment: `a->b` is a shortcut for `(*a).b`, so you can mechanically rewrite your code without `->`.

Comment: "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example".  I can't just paste this into a file and try to help you.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Since they're equivalent, it will obviously get the same error, so that's not much help.

Comment: `->` isn't the problem...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a complete example which we can compile and run ourselves. It should produce the exact same error which you get.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the correct way to implement a linked list.  It should look something more like this:

```
private:
    City *head;

CommunicationNetwork::CommunicationNetwork()
    : head(NULL)
{
}

CommunicationNetwork::~CommunicationNetwork()
{
    City *temp = head;
    while (temp)
    {
        City *next = temp->next;
        delete temp;
        temp = next;
    }
}

void CommunicationNetwork::buildNetwork()
{
    std::string citylist [] = {"Los Angeles", "Phoenix", "Denver", "Dallas", "St. Louis", "Chicago", "Atlanta", "Washington D.C.", "New York", "Boston"};

    // find the last node in the list...
    City *last = NULL;
    if (head)
    {
        last = head;
        while (last->next)
            last = last->next;        
    }

    // add the cities to the end of the list...
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        City *temp = new City;
        temp->cityName = citylist[i];
        temp->next = NULL;

        if (!head) head = temp;
        if (last) last->next = temp;
        last = temp;
    }
}
```

Which would then benefit from remembering the tail node alongside the head node so you don't have to hunt for it every time:

```
private:
    City *head, *tail;

CommunicationNetwork::CommunicationNetwork()
    : head(NULL), tail(NULL)
{
}

CommunicationNetwork::~CommunicationNetwork()
{
    City *temp = head;
    while (temp)
    {
        City *next = temp->next;
        delete temp;
        temp = next;
    }
}

void CommunicationNetwork::addCity(const std::string &cityName)
{
    City *temp = new City;
    temp->cityName = citylist[i];
    temp->next = NULL;

    if (!head) head = temp;
    if (tail) tail->next = temp;
    tail = temp;
}

void CommunicationNetwork::buildNetwork()
{
    std::string citylist [] = {"Los Angeles", "Phoenix", "Denver", "Dallas", "St. Louis", "Chicago", "Atlanta", "Washington D.C.", "New York", "Boston"};

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        addCity(citylist[i]);
}
```

And then, once you have it working, throw out the manual list and use `std::list` (or `std::forward_list` in C++11 and later) instead, let it manage the memory for you:

```
private:
    std::list<std::string> cities;

void CommunicationNetwork::addCity(const string &cityName)
{
    cities.push_back(cityName);
}

void CommunicationNetwork::buildNetwork()
{
    string citylist [] = {"Los Angeles", "Phoenix", "Denver", "Dallas", "St. Louis", "Chicago", "Atlanta", "Washington D.C.", "New York", "Boston"};

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        addCity(citylist[i]);
}
```

Comment: Extremely comprehensive. I owe you one

Comment: Kind of funny. This worked perfectly yesterday. I haven't changed any code, and now it doesn't work.